# Somar os valores de um count(*) no sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

sou novo em *sql* e estou com dificuldades para realizar a soma total de valores de um *count*, segue abaixo o código:

```
SELECT  A.Pais, count(*)
from Aeroportos A
left join Estacoes E
on A.Sigla = E.ICAO
where E.ICAO IS NULL
group by A.Pais
order by Pais;
```

Gostaria de além de ter a soma de aeroportos por país tambem ter a soma total de aeroportos, tentei utilizar a `SUM(count)` mas deu o erro:

> ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested.

Comment: Tudo na mesma query não vai funcionar.

Comment: poderia colocar um esboço das tabelas?

Comment: a soma total de aeroportos é basicamente `select count(*) from Aeroportos`

Comment: A contagem é somente dos `Aeroportos` que **não possuem** `Estações` relacionadas ?

Comment: Simm, somente dos aeroportos que nao tem estações

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT  
    A.Pais, 
    count(*) as qtd_pais,
    (select count(*) from Aeroportos) as total
from Aeroportos A
group by A.Pais
order by Pais;
```

> Acredito não ser a forma adequada pois acho que vai executar o count várias vezes desnecessariamente, dependendo de qual for sua real necessidade certamente tem forma melhor de fazer isso.

como você estava fazendo um join e em seguida um where onde a coluna do join fosse nula, retirei porque não estava correto.

A parte de pegar todos os aeroportos que não estão na tabela de estações, pode ser feita assim:

```
   SELECT  
        A.Pais, 
        count(*) as qtd_pais,
        (select count(*) from Aeroportos x where not exists (select 1 from Estacoes ex where ex.icao = x.sigla)  ) as total_sem_estacoes,
        (select count(*) from Aeroportos) as total
    from Aeroportos A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Estacoes e where e.icao = a.sigla)
    group by A.Pais
    order by Pais;
```

De quebra coloquei ali a quantidade total de aeroportos sem estações.

Comment: vou testar aqui ! obrigado,  o join que fez é para pegar apenas  os aeroportos que estão na tabela aeroporto e nao tem correspondencia na tabela estacoes . desculpe-me faltou eu explicar esssa parte do codigo rs

Comment: @LinkonLouvison adicionei como fazer a parte de não ter correspondências na tabela estacoes.

Comment: Obrigado @Rovann Linhalis   exatamente isso que eu queria fazer

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `UNION` para unir a contagem de `Aeroportos` em cada país com a quantidade total de `Aeroportos` em uma mesma consulta (sem nenhum *subselect*):

```
(SELECT a.Pais AS Pais, count(1) FROM Aeroportos a
LEFT JOIN Estacoes e ON (a.Sigla = e.ICAO)
WHERE e.ICAO IS NULL GROUP BY a.Pais)
UNION
(SELECT 'TOTAL' AS Pais, count(1) FROM Aeroportos a
LEFT JOIN Estacoes e ON (a.Sigla = e.ICAO)
WHERE e.ICAO IS NULL)
ORDER BY Pais
```

Veja funcionando no [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51e18/1).

Comment: Eu sei que não é o mesmo formato da consulta (separado em colunas), mas eu particularmente acho mais elegante assim (separado em linhas)

Comment: Ainda diria que é possível usar `UNION ALL`, visto que não haverá chance de existir tuplas repetidas nas duas consultas

Answer (score -1):

SELECT país, total, sum(total) over ()
From (select 
A.Pais, count(*) as total

from Aeroportos A
left join Estacoes E

on A.Sigla = E.ICAO
where E.ICAO IS NULL
group by A.Pais
order by Pais) t;

Aqui temos o uso de Windows functions. Usando a função sum com a cláusula over sem particionamento.
Tera algo assim como resultado...
País a   10.  10
País b    2.   12
País c.   25. 37

Veja que o total vai aparecer na última linha.
Se vc quiser que o total apareça em todas as linhas faca...

SELECT país, total, sum(total) over (partition by particao)
From (select 
A.Pais, count(*) as total
, 1 as particao
from Aeroportos A
left join Estacoes E

on A.Sigla = E.ICAO
where E.ICAO IS NULL
group by A.Pais
order by Pais) t;

Comment: Carlos, sempre que responder a uma pergunta tente deixar uma explicação  junto do código.